# Javascript Objects: What role do they play in real world apps?

Tags: javascript, object

I am learning Javascript from a book, and at the moment we are making 'Dog' objects using a constructor. They have properties and methods, and that's all cool. While the analogy works great, its hard to relate the concept to a real world app.
So, that What I want to find out: what do objects do in a real world app? If I want to build an app for people who can login, do things on the site, and logout, are these people going to be objects in the app?

PS: I know this might be too early for me, but I want to get the big picture too.

Comment: DOM objects are (exposed as) objects in JavaScript as well. It's pretty hard to use JavaScript (in a browser) and not use this "real world" example. Contrived examples are pretty easy to, well, contrive, but actually seeing how bundling things together into "objects" -- and when it is (or isn't) appropriate -- just comes with time/experience: just go with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have a "thing" or "object" in your app that has some properties and some operations you carry out using those properties or changing those properties, it will probably work well to use an object oriented design.  It works well as a means of organizing the data associated with the object and it works well as a means of expressing the methods or actions you carry out on those objects.

The more data you get, the more actions you have, the more types of objects you have, the more important it is to use an organizing paradigm like object oriented design and javascript objects in designing your own code.

In addition, most of the interface to things in the browser is already designed this way so you will want to be familiar with how to work with this type of code anyway.

If you have a very simple app, there's no imperative that you have to design your own objects.  When things are fairly simple, one can still write decent code without it.  But, it rarely hurts to start early in thinking about organizing your code and data around objects, even when things are simple.  I find it just lends to better organized and better thought-through code, even when it isn't necessarily required for the job at hand.  But, as soon as the app grows a little in complexity, a good object oriented design can really help a lot.

I'd suggest you learn the principles now, apply them to something simple in your first app and soon they will become part of your design thinking.